# Unity3d C# assignment error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm busy on working on my own Unity3d game, and here is one of scripts I currently have:

**HungerHandler.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using ProgressBar;

public class HungerHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    private ProgressBarBehaviour behaviour;
    public bool Start () {
        if (!this.behaviour = GameObject.Find("hungerBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>()) {
            return false;
        }
        this.behaviour.Value = 0f;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Add(int percentage){
        if (this.behaviour.Value < 100) {
            this.behaviour.Value = this.behaviour.Value + percentage;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool Damage(int percentage){
        if ((this.behaviour.Value - percentage) > 0) {
            this.behaviour.Value = this.behaviour.Value - percentage;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try to run my game I get an error:

```
Assets/custom/handlers/HungerHandler.cs(9,27): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer
```

This error is bugging me out since I so far have no problems with all the other basically identical scripts, so I'm wondering what am I doing wrong here? How can i fix this error?

Kind Regards,
Giovanni Le Grand

Comment: try !(this.behaviour = ...)

Comment: i have tried this, this did not change anything

Comment: You are mixing the assignement with a boolean test. I suppose that you want something like _if((this.behaviour = find....) == null) return false;_

Comment: @Steve this helped thanks! please put it as an answer so i can set it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Steve pointed out you are mixing assignment calls with boolean test. Probably this is what you want to do.

```
this.behaviour = GameObject.Find("hungerBar").GetComponent<ProgressBarBehaviour>();
if (this.behaviour == null) {
    return false;
}
```

But here is another thing. Since you are working with `MonoBehaviour`s - better to assign via Unity3d Editor references to other components instead of searching for them.